Why is 1 cm in tikzmath 28.5 cm long in a tikzpicture?
I define in tikzmath a variable of 1 cm.
\tikzmath{
   \oneCm = 1cm;
}

If I draw a line whose length is 1cm, and a second line whose length is \oneCm, they are not of the same length!
It's about 28.5 times bigger. Why?

MWE
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}         
\usetikzlibrary{math}   

\tikzmath{
   \oneCm = 1cm;
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,thin] (0, 0) -- ++(1cm,0) node[right]{1cm};
    \draw[blue,thin] (0, 10pt) -- ++(\oneCm,0) node[right]{oneCm};  
    \draw[green,thin] (0, -10pt) -- ++(28.5cm,0) node[right]{28.5cm};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The result from tikzmath will be in pt:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 
\usetikzlibrary{math}   

\tikzmath{
   \oneCm=1cm;
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,thin] (0, 0) -- ++(1cm,0) node[right]{1cm};
    \draw[blue,thin] (0, 10pt) -- ++(\oneCm pt,0) node[right]{oneCm};  
    \draw[green,thin] (0, -10pt) -- ++(28.5cm,0) node[right]{28.5cm};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Strange, but correct! Thx

@JosephMarie Quote from the tikz manual: "As was explained earlier, the parser commands like \pgfmathparse will always return a result without units in it and all dimensions that have a unit like 10pt or 1in will first be converted to TEX points (pt) and, then, the unit is dropped."

pgfmath is limited in range by using length registers (which is why I call it a dancing bear).  1pt is the middle of the range.  While 1cm is the default for tikz, it can be changed using [scale=...] etc.

@JohnKormylo scale doesn't do that. You can change the unit, but you need to say e.g. x=??,y=??. scale scales things after,
